# Hide "Delete Permanently" link from dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to hide / remove this "Delete Permanently" link from the trash view of orders dashboard. Is there a custom wp function that can do this? Thanks.

[image: delete permanently]

There are several tutorials that do the opposite though: (not what I want)
http://kingsolutions.org.uk/wordpress/wordpress-index/disable-wp-trash/
http://www.agentwp.com/how-to-disable-trash-in-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that using pure css

```
.order_title span.delete {display:none;}
```

and this should be your last line of defense

```
// disable delete entirely
function restrict_post_deletion($post_ID){
    $type = get_post_type($post_ID);
    if($type == 'shop_order'){
        echo "You are not authorized to delete this page.";
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('wp_trash_post', 'restrict_post_deletion', 10, 1);
add_action('before_delete_post', 'restrict_post_deletion', 10, 1);
```

what the above does is to get the post_id of the post you are deleting and see what type it is. If the type if a shop_order, do not allow them to delete by exiting the script entirely and show a message to the user so that they will stop doing silly things.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: input#delete_all.button.apply {display:none;} to hide Empty trash button.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty method:

Add this to your theme functions.php:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Then create that stylesheet and hide the span that has that link in it:

```
.order_title span.delete {display:none;}
```

If you're using a child theme (and you really should), change `get_template_directory_ui()` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`